# Monitor fails to sleep

Tags: debian, kde, wayland

My issue is that when timeout exceeds and monitor should switch off into sleep mode, it
instantly wakes up.
It happens on both Wayland and X11.
For X11 there is a workaround - disabling KScreen background service, however I couldn't find a working method for Wayland.
I am using the AMD RX 6500 XT with amdgpu driver, monitor connected into a HDMI
port.
This seems to be a known KDE bug(s) [(Wayland)](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452553) [(X11)](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=379474), but a fix has not been released yet. Also I filled a Debian [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1039504), it contains logs and some other information. I don't see the point in duplicating the logs here.

Is there any workaround for Wayland?

Debian 12.0, KDE